# This gives me a No overload for 'timer_Tick' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler<object>'

Tags: c#

After I changed the line 
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); to timer.Tick += timer_Tick; it still gives an error which is
No overload for 'timer_Tick' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'namespace App3

{

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();

    }
    private int myCount;
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        timer.Start();

    }


    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }

    private void Btm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App3.timer.Start();
    }

          private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myCount++;
        Label.Text = myCount.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Too much code. Just post what is necessary.

Comment: Are you sure you post the exact code which gives you problems? Because your `timer_Tick` method has the correct signature (`object, EventArgs`) and return type (`void`) for this delegate type. So all looks fine.

Comment: yes but for some reason the timer.tick line is the only one that's giving me a problem.

Comment: The problem does not reproduce with the code you post here. There must be something different with your code. Or do you define a type `EventArgs` that "hides" `System.EventArgs`?

Comment: `DispatcherTimer`, is the class you're referencing coming from `System.Windows.Threading` or another namespace? What .Net version are you building, and is this a Windows or mobile platform?

Comment: well its a blank app template in visual studios. I tried to make a stopwatch with a dispatcher timer. The only thing I left out were the stop and reset buttons.

Comment: @bluemagic that doesn't answer the questions.

Comment: I do not know what some of the questions mean. What does Jeppe mean by defining type eventargs that hides system.eventargs?

Comment: Ok, it is possible that you've accidentally overridden a class. To help determine this easily: Change all references of "DispatchTimer" to "System.Windows.Threading.DispatchTimer", also change "EventArgs" to "System.EventArgs"  This should eliminate the use of any overrides. Visual Studio will give you options to insert "using" declarations or define new classes when you use a type it doesn't recognize. It can be easy to accidentally select the "new class" option especially if the type is in an unreferenced assembly.

Comment: ok now its giving me "The type or namespace name 'Threading' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: There you have it... DispatcherTimer is part of WPF, (WindowsBase.dll) I hadn't spotted that this was likely a Windows Forms application. You should be able to just use the `System.Windows.Timer` object instead.